# Syntax highlighting js

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

### What I use and what I did

I have SyntaxHighlighter ([alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/))

```
<div class="question-text">
   <pre width="300px" class="brush: xml">
     <?= //php generated text ?>
   </pre>
</div>
```

And it perfectly works when I just write following code bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
```

### What I've tried to do

But there's an issue: I want to change brush dynamicaly when user selects it from the `select` :

```
<div class="nameselect">
    <select name="language">
       <option value=" ">Text</option>
       <option value="cpp">C++</option>
       <option value="csharp">C#</option>
       <option value="css">CSS</option>
       <option value="java">Java</option>
       <option value="js">JScript</option>
       <option value="php">PHP</option>
       <option value="py">Python</option>
       <option value="ruby">Ruby</option>
       <option value="sql">Sql</option>
       <option value="xml">HTML/XML</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I wrote some code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=language]', function () {
        var code = $(this).parent().parent().find("pre");

        code.addClass('brush: ' + $(this).val());
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

### What I think

Actually I found that this library changes my `<pre>` tag at all.
Any suggestions?

Changed `<pre class="brush: xml">` with value `<body>HTML's here</body>` is looks like:

```
    <div>
     <div id="highlighter_860958" class="syntaxhighlighter  xml">
       <div class="toolbar">
         <span>
           <a href="#" class="toolbar_item command_help help">?</a>
         </span>
     </div>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="gutter">
            <div class="line number1 index0 alt2">1</div>
          </td>
          <td class="code">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="line number1 index0 alt2">
                <code class="xml plain">&lt;</code>
                <code class="xml keyword">body</code>
                <code class="xml plain">&gt;HTML's here &lt;/</code>
                <code class="xml keyword">body</code>
                <code class="xml plain">&gt;</code>
              </div>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does the `<pre>` tag look like after you have changed the option? Does it change? Is there multiple classes now? Does the class even change? Sounds like you might need to remove the previous class before adding the new one

Comment: `it doesn't work` isn't a proper problem description. Provide a better explanation along with a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl I want to change brush dynamicaly when user selects it from the select.

It doesn't work means it doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I've updated my answer added poor but working example

Comment: @SterlingArcher it doesn't work at all with code that takes value from `select`